# number of times an experiment has to be repeated for optimal mean

Tags: average, standard-deviation, means

I am trying to get the total execution time of a program - running it different times will give different run times since it depends on a lot of factors. Thus, I am running this program multiple times and taking the mean running time. Is there a way to determine what is the optimal number of times this program should be run because running it too many times will lead to the waste of precious resources, while running it too little times will not allow me to gain reliable insights?

Comment: How much resource is insight worth to you?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question

Comment: In order to call something "optimal", you need to specify the objective function: precisely what quantity is being optimized?